# js ul lis aparecerem uma pós uma

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Então, tenho uma `ul` com suas `li's`.

Gostaria de fazer um `js` de forma que cada `li` aparecesse e sumisse (***automaticamente em um ciclo infinito***) para dar lugar à próxima `li`.  Isto é, que cada `li` aparece em sequência.

algo do Tipo:

HTML

```
    <ul>
      <li> 1 </li>
      <li> 2 </li>
      <li class="ativa"> 3 </li>
      <li> 4 </li>
    </ul>

...

    <ul>
      <li> 1 </li>
      <li> 2 </li>
      <li> 3 </li>
      <li class="ativa"> 4 </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    opacity:0;
}
.ativa {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Alguma dica?  Obrigado a quem pudesse ajudar!

Add:

Então, fiz esse jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {                           

  function addcls() {
    var li = $(".cycle-slideshow div.atividades ul li.ativa");
    li.removeClass('ativa');
    var current = li.removeClass('ativa');
    next = current.next().length ? current.next() : current.siblings().filter(':first');
    next.addClass('ativa');
  };

   setInterval(function () {
          addcls();
         }, 2000);  

});
```

E o css, assim:

```
div.atividades ul li{
    display:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    border:.1px  #000 solid;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:36px;
}


.ativa {
    display:block;
}
```

O que está dando erro é que, quando eu faço:

```
div.atividades ul li{
    display:none;
```

todas as lís somem: obviamente.
Porém, quando faço

```
next.addClass('ativa');
```

Embora no **espectro** as `lis` estejam ganhando e perdendo a `classe ativa` normalmente pelo **javascript**, o `display: block` não ocorre

Comment: Tipo um carrossel?

Comment: Se vc tiver um número específico de linhas(se for sempre o mesmo número de linhas) vc tb consegue fazer só com CSS sem precisar de JS fazendo apenas uma animação simples com CSS. Se te interessar posso fazer um exemplo e te responder.

Comment: com certeza quero.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso o mais apropriado é utilizar [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) para dar a temporização que está à espera. Em cada intervalo de tempo chamado pelo [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), passa para o próximo elemento (voltando a 0 se estiver no ultimo) e troca as classes. Para remover e adicionar classes pode utilizar [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Exemplo:

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let corrente = 2; //corresponde ao terceiro li (posições começam em 0)

setInterval(() => {
    lis[corrente].classList.remove("ativa"); //remove a classe no elemento corrente
    corrente = (corrente + 1) % lis.length; //passa para o próximo
    lis[corrente].classList.add("ativa"); //adiciona a classe no novo
}, 500); //500 milisegundos entre cada chamada
```

```css
li{
    opacity:0;
}
.ativa {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li class="ativa"> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
</ul>
```

Para adicionar uma classe utilizei `classList.add` e para remover `classList.remove`. No avanço para o próximo utilizei o operador `%` que acaba por fazer com que garantir que o elemento não passe do tamanho do array:

```
corrente = (corrente + 1) % lis.length;
```

Outra alternativa para isto seria:

```
corrente++;
if (corrente >= lis.length){
    corrente = 0;
}
```

Ou até com um ternário:

```
corrente = (corrente + 1 >= lis.length) ? 0 : corrente + 1;
```

Repare que eu escrevi manualmente a posição do elemento que começou ativo. Também consegue achar esse elemento dinamicamente utilizando por exemplo `findIndex`, que lhe dá a posição de determinado elemento:

```
let corrente = [...lis].findIndex(li => li.classList.contains("ativa"));
if (corrente == -1){ //se não existe 
    corrente = 0; //começa no primeiro
}
```

O teste feito dentro do `findIndex` verifica se o elemento tem a classe com `classList.contains`.

**Edit**:

Olhando para o seu código em JQuery, deve utilizar `show` e `hide` para mostrar e esconder os elementos respetivamente, pois é para esse fim que essas funções foram criadas. Se precisar de mostrar ou esconder de formas mais vistosas, tem varias variantes desde com slide, fade, etc...

Quanto ao avançar para o próximo elemento deve faze-lo à custa de `next()` e se vir que está num não valido volta ao primeiro, que obtem utilizando o pseudo seletor `:first`.

Assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var li = $(".cycle-slideshow div.atividades li.ativa");
  var first = $(".cycle-slideshow div.atividades ul li:first");
  li.show();
  
  function addcls() {  
    li.hide().removeClass("ativa");
    li = li.next();
    if (!li.length){ //se passou o ultimo
      li = first; //volta ao primeiro
    }
    li.show().addClass("ativa");
  };

   setInterval(addcls, 500);  
});
```

```css
div.atividades ul li{
    display:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    border:.1px  #000 solid;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:36px;
}

.ativa {
    color:lightBlue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
  <div class="atividades">
    <ul>
      <li> 1 </li>
      <li> 2 </li>
      <li class="ativa"> 3 </li>
      <li> 4 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Deixei a classe `ativa` na mesma mas sem o `display:block` pois isso já é feito no `show`. Agora só deve colocar outros estilos visuais que façam sentido para o elemento que está ativo.

Comment: então, esse: let corrente = 2;. deu erro no chrome. E essa linha também deu erro setInterval(() => {

Comment: @CarlosRocha Qual o erro que deu ?

Comment: então, erro não dá, porém só não roda

Comment: Tem o código colocado em que local da página ? Confirme que ele é executado depois de a pagina ser carregada, caso contrário não irá funcionar (assim como grande parte dos scripts). Pode fazer isso com  `window.onload` ou `$(document).ready` caso esteja a utilizar JQuery. Depois veja o que aparece inspecionar do navegador, tanto a nível de avisos como erros.

Comment: reveja o final a minha pergunta por favor. Adicionei detalhes. E sim, estou usando  $(document).ready

Comment: @Carlos Infelizmente você já mudou consideravelmente a pergunta, de um "como fazer isto", para "como ajustar o meu código em JQuery para fazer o que eu quero", tanto que nem tinha a tag inicial de JQuery na pergunta. Ainda assim vou ajustar a minha resposta, lembrando também que para todos os efeitos a resposta que tenho neste momento serve perfeitamente, como consegue ver no exemplo que dá para testar na resposta.

Comment: por favor, olhe em http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index2.php, funcionando com o erro

Comment: @CarlosRocha Editei para contemplar a parte de JQuery.

Comment: funcionou! Mas só tem um problema agora: quando abro a página pela primeira vez, o texto da primeira li não está aparecendo. Só aparece após o contador do setInterval rodar a primeira vez. Como corrigir isso para já aparecer de imediato quando a página abrir?

Comment: consegui: first.show(); abaixo de var first = $(".cycle-slideshow div.atividades ul li:first"); e antes da function()

Comment: @CarlosRocha De facto faltava esse pequeno pormenor, mas para coincidir com o meu exemplo na resposta em relação ao JQuery teria que ser `li.show();` antes da função. Já editei nesse sentido também

Comment: blz, tenho outra dúvida mas vou criar outra tópico.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos conforme solicitado no comentário segue uma opção fazendo apenas com CSS. Se vc quiser aumentar a duração da animação bastas aumentar o valor aqui `animation-duration:4s` *deixei comentado no código*

Veja o resultado:

```css
ul li {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-duration: 4s; /* duração da animação */
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) {
    animation-name: teste1;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    animation-name: teste2;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    animation-name: teste3;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
    animation-name: teste4;
}

@keyframes teste1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes teste2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes teste3 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    55% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    70% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes teste4 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    70% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    75% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 3 </li>
    <li> 4 </li>
</ul>
```

**OBS:** A animação é sincronizada para funcionar com 4 LI em 4 intervalos de 4. Se vc quiser alterar isso vai ter que mexer nas porcentagens do `@keyframes` até "equalizar" direitinho.